# Formula for giving always the same sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

I have a variable in excel that starts at 1  and it keeps incrementing indefinitely (i named it lr). I want that when lr gets to 21 it stop getting it's actual value and restart valuing 1. **When it gets to 31, it must return 11. Or when it gets to 32, it must return 12. But when it gets to 41 it must return 1 again**. As lr gets large, I want it to still return numbers between the $ 1, ... , 20 $ interval. One example would be 21 returns, 1 ; 22 returns, 2 ... 61, returns 1, 62 returns 2, 63 returns 3. I can't seem to find the recursion of this progression. I've tried to fit the geometric progression formula but with no luck. This always happened when you have to show 'x' elements in a page and needs a variable to keep growing, but this variable must return numbers in a specific interval. Like if you had a variable to return the number of ith question (15 questions are showed per page by default) of math.stackexchange (in the questions page) as the pages keep growing, how to do that recursively? Through a formula?

Comment: $Rem (21/20) =1$

$Rem (22/20)=2$
.
. 
$Rem (41/20)=1$

Comment: It's called "modulus", and it looks like the modulus should be 10... Unless you mistook and intended to say 1..20 for 41.. 60 instead of for 31..60

Comment: @Cardinal Im terribly sorry l, I've made a typo. In the edit I've made now, there's a bold part indicating the correction. Thanks for taking your time to help!

Comment: @abiessu I'm sorry, you were correct, it was indeed a typo!

Comment: This is not rocket science. See my answer, and especially the addendum I just added.

Comment: The comment tree was trimmed in response to a system flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use $$1+\operatorname{MOD}(\operatorname{lr}-1,20)$$
to convert $\operatorname{lr}$ as you describe.

You can keep incrementing $\operatorname{lr}$, but this expression as a function of $\operatorname{lr}$ will assume values in the range $1-20$ cyclically.

**Addendum:** A somewhat more general function that maps successive integers onto a cycle of $n$ successive integers is $$y = b + \operatorname{MOD}(x-a,n)$$

Here, the $n$ integers $a,a+1,\ldots,a+n-1$ are mapped successively to the $n$ integers $b,b+1,\ldots,b+n-1$. The next integer $a+n$ starts the cycle over again, being mapped to $b$ just as $a$ was. And so on.

In your case, we took $a=b=1$ and $n=20$.

Comment: "Or when it gets to $32$, it must return $2$."  I think your answer is correct for what is intended, BTW.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks very much. Just a side note, if one wants to use it in VBA it should add the function below prior. Function `XLMod(a, b)
    ' This replicates the Excel MOD function
    XLMod = a - b * Int(a / b)
End Function`

Comment: Some languages (in particular, C and friends) have a built-in operator "%" that returns the remainder of an integer division. That's what you need. So one would have (operating with integer values) 7/3 = 2 and 7%3 = 1. I don't know about VBA, haven't used it much.

Comment: Google says VBA does indeed have such an operator, so you don't need to redefine it. It is "Mod", used in expressions like x = a Mod b. See [this link](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/mod-operator.html) for details.

Comment: @MPW I know it has, but if you use it like it is you won't be able to fit with your answer. I've tried to use MOD directly (making the required modifications, of course) and it failed. ps. I was about to ask you if existed the general function you provided in the addendum but then wouldn't want to become the traditional stackexchange mendicant.. haha you've read my mind thanks for such perfect answer, math is beautiful!

Comment: Surely $b+((x-a)\operatorname{Mod} n)$ does the trick in VBA?

Comment: And thanks for the praise, glad to help.